# n1ql query to update multiple parameters in array of json data

Tags: json, couchbase, sql++

Following is the sample document ( userdetails) in couchbase.

```
{
"friends": [
  {
    "company": "microsoft",
    "firstname": "criss",
    "lastname": "angel"
  },
  {
    "company": "google",
    "firstname": "captain",
    "lastname": "america"
  }
]}
```

based on the "company", i want to change the "firstname" and "lastname"

**N1ql query ( to update single parameter (firstname) )**

```
update default use keys "userdetails" set a.firstname="xyz" for a in friends when a.company="microsoft" end returning friends
```

Above query works perfectly.
but Im struggling in writting query for updating two parameters ( firstname,lastname)

**N1ql query ( to update two parameter)**

```
update default use keys "userdetails" set a.firstname="abc",a.lastname="xyz" for a in friends when a.company="microsoft" end returning friends
```

Above query, is updating only "lastname".

**output**

```
{
"friends": [
  {
    "company": "microsoft",
    "firstname": "criss",
    "lastname": "xyz"
  },
  {
    "company": "google",
    "firstname": "captain",
    "lastname": "america"
  }
]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each SET term is independent, so you can do the following:

```
UPDATE default
USE KEYS "userdetails"
SET a.firstname="abc" FOR a IN friends WHEN a.company="microsoft" END,
    a.lastname="xyz" FOR a IN friends WHEN a.company="microsoft" END
RETURNING friends;
```

To answer your comment, the following two forms avoid the double loop. You can measure with actual data to see which form gives the best performance.

```
UPDATE default
USE KEYS "userdetails"
SET friends[i] = {"firstname":"abc", "lastname":"xyz", "company":"microsoft"} FOR i : a IN friends WHEN a.company="microsoft" END
RETURNING friends;

UPDATE default
USE KEYS "userdetails"
SET friends[i] = OBJECT_PUT(OBJECT_PUT(a, "firstname", "abc"), "lastname", "xyz") FOR i : a IN friends WHEN a.company="microsoft" END
RETURNING friends;
```

Comment: is this efficient way to update?
wont it affect performance. ?

Comment: the query is throwing error. @geraldss
`[
  {
    "code": 3000,
    "msg": "syntax error - at :",
    "query_from_user": "UPDATE default\r\nUSE KEYS \"userdetails\"\r\nSET friends[i] = {\"firstname\":\"abc\", \"lastname\":\"xyz\", \"company\":\"microsoft\"} FOR i : a IN friends WHEN a.company=\"microsoft\" END\r\nRETURNING friends;",
    "query_with_limit": "UPDATE default\r\nUSE KEYS \"userdetails\"\r\nSET friends[i] = {\"firstname\":\"abc\", \"lastname\":\"xyz\", \"company\":\"microsoft\"} FOR i : a IN friends WHEN a.company=\"microsoft\" END\r\nRETURNING friends;"
  }
]`

Comment: Are you using 4.5 Beta? You may need to use that.