# How do I use UPDATE in couchbase for nested document

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Following is the json format we have as user details

```
{
  "detail": {
  "about": "Ha Ha Ha Andhera kayam hm rahe.",
  "approved_point": "0",
  "devices": [
    "{\"device_id\":\"test\" , \"fcm_id\":\"test\" }",
    "{\"device_id\":\"wow\" , \"fcm_id\":\"test\" }"
  ],
  "email": "xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
  "email_verify": "1",
  "facebook_access_token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "facebook_id": "10207936631359310",
  "gender": "male",
  "home": [
    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "28.53640100",
    "77.22342200",
    "SOSM9C"
  ],
  "last_visited": "12345",
  "location": "New Delhi",
  "mobile": "9582058100",
  "mobile_verify": "",
  "name": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX YYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
  "office": [
    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "28.54951300",
    "77.26780900",
    "MMI000"
  ],
  "password": "523198ad0b9364bcb44f6154a6d5b53d",
  "permissions": [
    "115",
    "103",
    "101",
    "200",
    "112"
  ],
  "registered_timestamp": "2016-06-10 18:55:52",
  "social_id": "112",
  "twitter_access_token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "twitter_id": "198879865",
  "unapproved_point": "1050",
  "user_id": "305722704",
  "user_name": "mustanish123",
  "user_photo": "mustanish123.jpg"
}
```

}

Now what I want to do is that,I want to update device,last_visited,
permission field in one single update query.I can update the above with individual query.

I tried to use this link but did not work me

[n1ql query to update multiple parameters in array of json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152577/n1ql-query-to-update-multiple-parameters-in-array-of-json-data)

Comment: You can use multiple set clause. Please post the query you tried and not working.  or show the expected output of the fields after update.

Comment: @vsr I was able to execute that query, It was very stupid of me not to think of it in that way.thanks.